# How to delete the rows containing tweet ids from csv files which are invalid

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i have an old dataset containing tweet ids in a csv file , but when I am trying to use now through twitter api,they are invalid.I want to remove all such ids which are invalid,or for which status is unavailable.
Please help me with the code.

Comment: You didn't share any code - how do you expect anyone to help you here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.